# How to remove duplicates from a huge xml file but keeping the ones with the most recent 'changedate' attribute using XML::Twig in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have the following huge XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "56.dtd">
<body>
<tu changedate="20130625T175037Z"">
  <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
    <prop type="x-context-pre">&lt;seg&gt;Some text.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
    <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;Other text.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
    <seg>The text I'm interested.</seg>
  </tuv>
  <tuv xml:lang="it">
    <seg>And it's translation in italian.</seg>
  </tuv>
 </tu> 

 .... followed by other <tu>'s
</body>
```

I'm using an hash to "associate each "seg" content with it's changedate, so that I can check, using a handler, if the "seg" already exists and then, see if the version found is older and if so, delete it. The problem with this approach is that if the version found is newer there is no way to delete the older version wich was parsed way back in the xml file. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
use 5.010;

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);

my $filename = 'pt_PT-it_IT.tmx';
my $out_filename = 'out.xml';
open my $out, '>', $out_filename;
binmode $out;

my $original_twig = new XML::Twig (pretty_print => 'indented', twig_handlers => {tu => \&original_tu});
$original_twig->parsefile($filename);
$original_twig->flush($out);
close $out;

{ my %md5;
sub original_tu {
my($twig, $original_tu) = @_;
#print $original_tu->text;
my $original_seg = $original_tu->first_child('tuv')->first_child('seg')->text;

my $original_changedate = $original_tu->att('changedate');
$original_changedate = substr $original_changedate, 0, 8;
$hash = md5(original_seg);
if (exists($md5{$hash})) {
    if (($md5{$hash}) gt $original_changedate) {
        print "================================\n";
            print "DELETED\n";
            print $original_seg;
            print "\n BECAUSE ORIGINAL DATE: ";
            print $original_changedate;
            print " IS OLDER THAN THE FOUND ONE: ";
            print $other_changedate;
            print "\n=================================\n";
            $original_tu->delete(); 

        }


    }
else
    $md5{$hash} = $original_changedate;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any light in how can I (to recapitulate) remove duplicates with the most recent value of 'changedate' in a huge (700 MB) XML file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not comletely clear to me how `tu` and `seg` are related. So it's hard for me to give you code that may not do what you want.

So just a little comment, which I am sure you've already considered: I think you're going to have to do this in 2 passes:

1. first pass identify the most recent change for each `seg`, store this data in a hash `{ md5 => date }`, for all `tu`, the way you create `$md5{$hash}`
2. then in a 2cd pass remove all the `tu` that have a `changedate` lower (or just different) from the stored value.

Hopefully the hash is small enough to fit in memory. It's slower (and less satisfying!) than a 1-pass process, but it should work.